# is it possible to execute a mailler when the server start without opening the application ? the application is a ruby app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want my application to send mails every month to the users even if nobody is logged in , i'm on a ruby application . can anyone tell me is this possible and how ? thanks .

Comment: The most common way is probably to have [`Cron`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) using `rails runner` to call a method in your app once a month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use cron directly or you could configure this using the whenever gem to keep your cron config within your application.

Add the gem to your Gemfile

```
gem 'whenever', '0.9.4', require: false
```

Now wheneverize your application

```
$ cd myapp
$ wheneverize .
```

This will create a config file at `config/schedule.rb`

Add a task definition to `config/schedule.rb`, e.g

```
every :month do
  runner "MyMailer.my_email.deliver_now"
end
```

If you are using Capistrano to deploy your application you can use the Capistrano recipes provided to have `whenever` update your cron tasks on deploy, if you can run

```
$ whenever -w
```

to update the crontab

Comment: i guess it doesn't work on windows , is there is any other solution ??